# IF or CASE in WHERE clause of SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

My problem is I have a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE STATUSID = @PARAMETER
```

Then I want to create that query into dynamic one like this:

```
IF @PARAMETER IS 1 THEN STATUSID = 1
IF @PARAMETER IS 2 THEN STATUSID = 2
IF @PARAMETER IS 3 THEN STATUSID = 1 OR STATUSID = 2
```

Can anyone give me a sample query how to do this? I just want to do this inside `WHERE` clause so that I can minimize my line of code.

Comment: Please don't shout. We're not deaf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use OR

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE (STATUSID = 1 and @PARAMETER = 1)
OR (STATUSID = 2 and @PARAMETER = 2)
or (STATUSID in (1,2) and @PARAMETER = 3)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Use CASE Clause to get result :  

SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE STATUSID = CASE 
  WHEN @PARAMETER = 1 THEN 1 
  WHEN @PARAMETER = 2 THEN 2
  WHEN @PARAMETER = 3 THEN STATUSID END
```

Comment: AND/OR is usually easier to optimize than case expression in the where clause.

Comment: i got some error near = 1 and so on. the or statement work but thanks anyway

Comment: the last part of your query will not solved my problem `WHEN @PARAMETER = 3 THEN STATUSID` because I have a status id 4 and so on that i dont want to select also

Answer (score 2):

Another solution would be to first check the parameter and then execute the corresponding query.

```
IF @PARAMETER = 1 THEN SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE STATUSID = 1
IF @PARAMETER = 2 THEN SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE STATUSID = 2
IF @PARAMETER = 3 THEN SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE STATUSID = 1 OR STATUSID = 2
```

Is the easiest for the engine to optimize.

Comment: yah this is right but i just want to do it in just 1 line of code. Because in my query it contains many line so if i used that kind of trick my line code will become x3 because of `if`

Comment: Indeed, I also use the accepted solution for this reason, but it seemed appropriate to show more options. There are occasions where the engine has a hard time optimizing that kind of filter.